# Text changed in android

Tags: android

How can I call API on`TextChange Method of Textwatcher` in `android`, I have the requirement that I want to change my text of `editText onTextchange` method but by using `API`.

Comment: Do you have face any problem with Textwatcher on edittext.?

Comment: Yes , i got stuck at point please help me out there

Answer (score 1):

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

     //Here Call Your API 
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    }
});
```

from your question , this is the first step you have to do . if you specify your problem in detail , we might be able to help you in detail .